# How can I improve the debug speed of Qt5.9.2 + MinGW + GDB on windows10

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, mingw32

Since from Qt 5.9, the Qt for windows has packed all compilers in one package, so I installed two compilers(MinGW5.3.0 and MSVC2015) and the corresponding debuggers(GDB and CDB). And I did some comparison about these two debuggers. The result is that when push button F5, the starting speed of MinGW+GDB is obviously slower than the MSVC2015+CDB. And for MinGW+GDB, after the application window has shown, for some operation, such as open a choose file dialog, the application will stuck for several seconds, while the MSVC+CDB doesn't have this problem.

So I'd like to know if there is a way to improve the debug speed of MinGW+GDB under the windows platform or this problem is just an unavoidable problem under the windows platform. Thank you!